# Kendo UI grid - throw Error(kendo.format("Cannot call method '{0}' of {1} before it is initialized",t,r))

Tags: javascript, user-interface, grid, kendo-ui

I have `tabstrip` with two tab. On each tab i have one grid with paging.
My configuration for grid is on the client side. When I fast switch beetween tab then I get exception from javascript:

```
"throw Error(kendo.format("Cannot call method '{0}' of {1} before it is initialized",t,r))"
```

Below section for paging configuration in grid:

```
[...]

pageable: {
                    pageSizes: [5, 10, 20],
                    input: true
           },
[...]
```

Have you any idea how prevent this error?

Comment: Not very clear what the problem is. More code or a jsbin/jsfiddle demo would help us understand your case better.

Comment: It's look like that pageable initialization occurs error. When I turn of pagaable then is ok. I load content by ajax. When content load is success then I init and config kendo grid control by client side.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and yes there is a fix for it, basically you just need to destroy the grid before you move to new tab...

The best way to tackle this is by using this function while will look for kendo grid and destroy them

```
$("[kendo-grid]").each(function(idx,kGrid){
                                var dataObj=$(kGrid).data();
                                for(mData in dataObj)
                                {
                                    if(typeOf dataObj[mData] != "string")
                                    {
                                        if("destroy" in dataObj[mData])
                                        {
                                            dataObj[mData].destroy();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            })
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -3):

Not clear what is the exact problem... Looks like sync issue.

Try loading content with async: false

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer